# How can I create a fancy TOC with background colors?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, color, tocloft, titletoc

I'm trying to create a TOC that looks like the following:

[image]

I already tried different ways of achieving it with `titletoc` and `tocloft` but I'm not getting the desired output. I would like the links to be clickable so I can go to the clicked section. Here is the code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Document Revision History}
\section*{Contacts}

\section{Executive Summary}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Test Approach and Methodology}
\subsection{SCOPE}

\section{Assessment Summary And Findings Overview}
\section{Findings Technical Details}

\subsection{Vuln 1}

\subsubsection{Description}
\subsubsection{Code Location}
\subsubsection{Recommendation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a job for tcolorbox.

Comment: So you have a page that is colour black with a different colour background for sections. What about the rest of the document?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer. Being colour blind I don't do colours but the following does typeset the ToC entries left justified and no dotted leaders

```
% colouredtocprob.tex  SE 581740

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Document Revision History}
\section*{Contacts}

\section{Executive Summary}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Test Approach and Methodology}
\subsection{SCOPE}

\section{Assessment Summary And Findings Overview}
\section{Findings Technical Details}

\subsection{Vuln 1}

\subsubsection{Description}
\subsubsection{Code Location}
\subsubsection{Recommendation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good suggestion (also borrowed Sir `Peter Wilson` suggestion too), but it works partially:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{black!75}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{snugshade}\color{white}}
\section*{Document Revision History}
\section*{Contacts}

\section{Executive Summary}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{snugshade}\color{black}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{shadecolor}{black!40}\begin{snugshade}\color{white}}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Test Approach and Methodology}
\subsection{SCOPE}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{snugshade}\color{black}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{snugshade}\color{white}}
\section{Assessment Summary And Findings Overview}
\section{Findings Technical Details}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{snugshade}\color{black}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{shadecolor}{black!40}\begin{snugshade}\color{white}}
\subsection{Vuln 1}

\subsubsection{Description}
\subsubsection{Code Location}
\subsubsection{Recommendation}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{snugshade}\color{black}}

\end{document}
```

[image]